# Select timestamp data for specific time range each day

Tags: postgresql, sql-timestamp

I have a postgresql table with a column of type `timestamp without timezone`. Every row increases/decreases by 1 minute eg:

```
2015-07-28 01:35:00
2015-07-28 01:34:00
2015-07-28 01:33:00
...
...
2015-07-27 23:59:00
2015-07-27 23:58:00
2015-07-27 23:57:00
```

I am trying to write a query that will select all the rows between a certain date range, but also during a specific time range for those days, eg: Select all rows between 2015-05-20 to 2015-06-20 during 08:00:00 to 16:00:00.

Everything i've tried so far doesn't seem to take both the date + time requirement into account.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if you want all rows for the days specified, but exclude rows from those days where the time part is outside of `08:00` to `16:00` the following should do it:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column::date between date '2015-05-20' and date '2015-06-20'
  and the_column::time between time '08:00:00' and '16:00:00'
```

The expression `the_column::date` is called a cast and will convert the `timestamp` to a `date` removing the time information. `the_column::time` extracts the time part of the `timestamp` column.

The `between` operator will include the boundaries (e.g. rows with a time precisely at `16:00:00`). If you don't want that you will need to change the `between` condition to a corresponding `>` and `<` condition.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of how to cast which was why I was struggling.

Comment: Follow up question @a_horse_with_no_name .. I
f I want to get the between `16:00:00` on the current day and  `08:00:00` the **next day**, how can that be done?

Comment: `between current_date + time '16:00' and (current_date + 1)::timestamp`

Comment: see this about using `between` https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29

Comment: @Curtis: I am not using `between` with a timestamp. And I pointed out the downsides of using it.